# Получение значения тега w:char

Tags: c#, openxml

Использую OpenXML SDK 2.5. Требуется, помимо текста `w:t`, считать из файла *.docx* значения спецсимволов из `SymbolChar`.
Пытаюсь получить доступ к значению:

```
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("myfile.docx", true)
{
    foreach (var par in doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>())
    {
        foreach (var run in par.Elements<Run>())
        {
            if (run.GetFirstChild<SymbolChar>().Char.HasValue)
                richTextBox1.Text += run.GetFirstChild<SymbolChar>().Char.Value
        }
    }
}
```

Однако не получается. Что я делаю не так?